# Pod install installs deprecated react and creates a build error 'React/RCTBridge.h' not found

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I recently added some pods and ran pod install to a previously working project and now I get a warning that `React has been deprecated` and seems to have problems linking to React with a build error `React/RCTBridge.h' file not found.  This type of issue seems to happen with several different libraries I try to add via pod install.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `ViroKit` from `../node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/ViroRenderer/`
Fetching podspec for `ViroReact` from `../node_modules/react-viro/ios/`
Fetching podspec for `react-native-camera` from `../node_modules/react-native-camera`
Downloading dependencies
Using AWSCore (2.6.16)
Using AWSDynamoDB (2.6.16)
Using BoringSSL (10.0.2)
Using Crashlytics (3.10.1)
Using Fabric (1.7.6)
Using Firebase (4.13.0)
Using FirebaseABTesting (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.2.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (4.6.1)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.20)
Using FirebaseDatabase (4.1.5)
Using FirebaseDynamicLinks (2.3.2)
Using FirebaseFirestore (0.11.0)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.10)
Using FirebaseMessaging (2.2.0)
Using FirebasePerformance (1.1.3)
Using FirebaseRemoteConfig (2.1.3)
Using FirebaseStorage (2.2.0)
Using FirebaseSwizzlingUtilities (1.0.1)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.6)
Using GVRAudioSDK (1.120.0)
Using GVRSDK (1.120.0)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.0)
Using Protobuf (3.5.0)
Installing React (0.11.0)
Using ViroKit (1.0)
Using ViroReact (1.0)
Using gRPC (1.11.0)
Using gRPC-Core (1.11.0)
Using gRPC-ProtoRPC (1.11.0)
Using gRPC-RxLibrary (1.11.0)
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Using nanopb (0.3.8)
Installing react-native-camera (1.1.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 14 dependencies from the Podfile and 34 total pods installed.

[!] React has been deprecated
```

Is there a correct way I should have React configured in my Xcode or pod file that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project in Xcode? This message is normally followed by cleaning everything and rebuilding.

Comment: yes I tried cleaning - I think it's related to the deprecated react references in the library pods - adding the react references in the new way - I'm not sure which subspecs to add as they are throwing build errors

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:
Add to podfile

pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'yoga', path: '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'